# Fixing pipe/tube from dishwasher to disposal

Tags: plumbing, pipe, garbage-disposal

Photos attached. This seperated today and caused a mess. I have no idea how this was originally connected.

There is a copper pipe inside of a black tube.

I believe the black tube was clamped to the disposal outlet because the black tube doesn’t not fit over, or into, the disposal outlet.

I was also thinking perhaps I should pull the copper pipe out a bit, slide that into the disposal outlet and then clamp it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Home Depot sells a connector from the black tube to the garbage disposal.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Thanks for answering your question; would you mind posting a picture of the solution so that others with the same problem will see how you solved it? Thanks.

Comment: Your dishwasher hose should be connected to an **air gap** or have a **high hose loop**. If one hose goes from the dishwasher to the top of the sink/counter and another hose comes down to the disposal then you have a traditional air gap. If it is one hose straight from dishwasher to disposal then you need to make sure it loops up as high as possible under the edge of the sink/counter. This provides an important safety mechanism to prevent dirty water from flowing from the sink/disposal into the dishwasher.